# Angular: Different ways to instantiate a class in a component?

Tags: angular, typescript

Assuming Project is an object class I created to be used in a component. Can I instantiate a class with the `new` keyword

`project = new Project();`

**AND** a constructor?

`constructor(public project: Project) {}`

Are these the same? If they are the same, which is preferred?

Comment: I assume you are trying to use some of the methods and properties within that `Project` class? May I know if they are static?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I instantiate a class with the new keyword?

Yes you can, but it will create an object that is **not injectable**.

> Are these the same?

**No, they are not the same**. When you declare the object as an argument in the constructor that object is injectable and is declared as a dependency of that class in the Angular framework.

From the official Angular docs on [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

> In Angular, the DI framework provides declared dependencies to a class
>   when that class is instantiated